# Open any type of files as images

Tags: android, windows, file, types

I want to open any type of files (include of no-extensions) as images that can make me easier to manage the files (cut, copy, delete), so if the files can be opened as images, the images will be shown.

When i'm trying to find it in many website there are only two type of steps for this problem :

1. Rename or convert it into image types ( .jpg, .png, .tiff, etc.) and then manage it with built-in image viewer. It's not effective, because this step will change the original data and damage the original files.
2. Make some preview thumbnails( .thumb) of the files, and then manage the original files by viewing the preview. It's not effective too, thumbnails will make confuse and makes bigger size.

So, anybody can help me for any solution of my problem? I think it can be more useful in Windows or Android. Thanks for any answers.

- I'm sorry for my bad english

Comment: For the first solution from your question, copying the file to a new location with the extension, wouldn't that solve your problem?

Comment: Yes, it's solve it. But may not efficient if I want to delete the original files. I must select the spesific files name-by-name manually.

Comment: I feel that can be solved by using some data structure. ie. When you are copying the original to a new location, you can create a mapping of duplicate file to original file. This way you will be able to instantly find the original from a copy.
The only problem I can see here is additional usage of space and if the Images are even if in few MBs you can still copy them since storage is not very expensive and availble in ample for most of the case.

Comment: That's what I see. It's useful when we use in some of files. But if we use it in huge number of files I think may waste many times to do it. It's similiar solution with number (2).